# Select the most recently added row where three columns are the same

Tags: mysql

I have the following table named classamendments,

```
+ID  |    date    |   time    |   groupnummber    | date added     |  type
============================================================================
 1   |  16-05-18  | 07:00     |   1               | 16/05/ 12:00:00| add 
 2   |  16-05-18  | 07:00     |   1               | 16/05/ 12:05:00| rem
 3   |  16-05-18  | 07:00     |   1               | 16/05/ 12:06:00| add
 4   |  16-05-20  | 15:00     |   4               | 16/05/ 18:49:00| add
 5   |  16-05-20  | 15:00     |   4               | 16/05/ 20:10:00| rem
```

how would I select the most recent entry where date,time and groupnumber where the same, (rows 3 and 5)

Comment: Have you something try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way uses a correlated subquery in the `where`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.dateadded = (select max(t2.dateadded)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.date = t.date and t2.time = t.time and
                           t2.groupnumber = t.groupnumber
                    );
```

This query can take advantage of an index on `t(date, time, groupnumber, dateadded)` and should be quite fast with the right index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT date, time, groupnummber, MAX(date_added) AS date_added
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY date, time, groupnummber 
) AS t2 ON t1.date = t2.date AND
           t1.time = t2.time AND
           t1.groupnummber = t2.groupnummber AND 
           t1.date_added = t2.date_added
```